# Display part of a table in one page and the rest in another page in XSL-FO

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

I have a table which could have n number of rows. The table is present inside a block-container with absolute-position="absolute" so that the table has a fixed position.

Now the number of rows that i need to present on the first is only 5. If in case its more than 5 i need to present the rest in a new page and add a footer in the front page that says continues in next page.

How do i achieve this using XSLT? I am using Apache fop to generate AFP and PDF

Please find below snippet of code that i have written already.

```
<fo:block-container border="solid 1px" absolute-position="absolute" left="3.09in" top="2.95in" width="4.765in" height="1.1in" overflow="hidden">
        <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
            <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block padding-left="2.0mm" padding="2pt" font-family="TelenorTFBold" font-size="11pt" font-weight="normal" fox:border-before-start-radius="5pt" fox:border-before-end-radius="5pt" fox:border-after-start-radius="5pt" fox:border-after-end-radius="5pt" background-color="#f8f8f8">
                            <xsl:call-template name="LabelText">
                                <xsl:with-param name="Code" select="concat($language, 'Number')"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block padding-left="2.0mm" padding="2pt" font-family="TelenorTFBold" font-size="11pt" font-weight="normal" fox:border-before-start-radius="5pt" fox:border-before-end-radius="5pt" fox:border-after-start-radius="5pt" fox:border-after-end-radius="5pt" background-color="#f8f8f8">
                            <xsl:call-template name="LabelText">
                                <xsl:with-param name="Code" select="concat($language, 'duedate')"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block text-align="right" padding-left="2.0mm" padding="2pt" font-family="TelenorTFBold" font-size="11pt" font-weight="normal" fox:border-before-start-radius="5pt" fox:border-before-end-radius="5pt" fox:border-after-start-radius="5pt" fox:border-after-end-radius="5pt" background-color="#f8f8f8">
                            <xsl:call-template name="LabelText">
                                <xsl:with-param name="Code" select="concat($language, 'Total')"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
                    <xsl:for-each select="InstallmentPlan">
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell font-family="TelenorTF" font-size="7pt" font-weight="normal">
                                            <fo:block padding-after="0.15cm" white-space-collapse="false">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="InstallmentNumber"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell font-family="TelenorTF" font-size="7pt" font-weight="normal">
                                            <fo:block padding-after="0.15cm" white-space-collapse="false">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="DueDate"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell font-family="TelenorTF" font-size="7pt" font-weight="normal">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right" padding-after="0.15cm" white-space-collapse="false">
                                                <xsl:call-template name="format_amount">
                                                    <xsl:with-param name="amount" select="Amount"/>
                                                </xsl:call-template>
                                            </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                    </xsl:for-each>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>     
    </fo:block-container>
```

Look and feel of the output :

Page 1:

```
Number        Duedate        Total
1             01-08-2024     12345
2             01-09-2024     12344
3             01-07-2024     12345
4             01-06-2024     12345
5             01-03-2024     12345
                             Continues on next page

Information section
".................."
```

Page 2:

```
 Number        Duedate        Total
 6             01-08-2024     12345
 7             01-09-2024     12344
 8             01-07-2024     12345
 9             01-06-2024     12345
 10            01-03-2024     12345
```

Comment: Why are you placing it in an absolute-positioned block?

Comment: Placing it in a block container since i need a fixed position to the table :?

Comment: Are other things flowing around it? Just stating that it needs to be in some position is not enough to describe the situation. You would need to explain things like ... it could be 2, 3, ? Pages. A single row could be 1,2,? Lines.

Answer (score 0):

I won't try to include the XSLT suggestion into your XSL-FO markup but you can positional grouping in XSLT 2/3 e.g. something like

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="InstallmentPlan" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv 5">
<!-- now here create a page/table section for each group and inside process current-group() to output the rows of each group/page -->

</xsl:for-each-group>
```